# /bin/cp: cannot open 'libmxml.so' for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, symlink

I was running a make to produce a cross-compiled Linux kernel, with --target=mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc, --host=mips-linux, CC= mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc, --build=x86_64-linux-gnu.
The build environment is Ubuntu 20.04.
I encountered the following error:

```
Makefile:147: target 'install-libmxml.so.1.4' does not exist
/usr/bin/install -c -d /home/minipc/econet/lib_install
/bin/rm -f libmxml.so
/bin/ln -s /home/minipc/econet/apps/public/mxml-2.4/libmxml.so.1.4 libmxml.so
/bin/rm -f libmxml.so.1
/bin/ln -s /home/minipc/econet/apps/public/mxml-2.4/libmxml.so.1.4 libmxml.so.1
/bin/rm -f /home/minipc/econet/lib_install/libmxml.so*
/bin/cp -rf libmxml.so* /home/minipc/econet/lib_install
/bin/cp: cannot open 'libmxml.so' for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
make[1]: *** [Makefile:153: install-libmxml.so.1.4] Error 1
```

The Makefile snippet code is:

```
146 install-libmxml.so.1.4:
147         $(INSTALL_DIR) $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)
148         $(RM) libmxml.so
149         $(LN) $(shell pwd)/libmxml.so.1.4 libmxml.so
150         $(RM) libmxml.so.1
151         $(LN) $(shell pwd)/libmxml.so.1.4 libmxml.so.1
152         $(RM) $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)/libmxml.so*
153         $(CP) libmxml.so* $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)
```

And I checked that symbolic link libmxml.so and libmxml.so.1 have been correctly created.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 minipc minipc    55 Aug 13 22:35 libmxml.so -> /home/minipc/econet/apps/public/mxml-2.4/libmxml.so.1.4*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 minipc minipc    55 Aug 13 22:35 libmxml.so.1 -> /home/minipc/econet/apps/public/mxml-2.4/libmxml.so.1.4*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 minipc minipc 30084 Aug 13 22:35 libmxml.so.1.4*
```

And I tried the following in the direcotry /home/minipc/econet/apps/public/mxml-2.4

```
$ /bin/cp -rf libmxml.so* /home/minipc/econet/lib_install
```

It created the desired result with no any warning or error reported.

So I wonder why it reported error in Make process?

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by this recipe:

```
$(CP) libmxml.so* $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)
```

It maybe that coping two symbolic links to the same file to the same directory simultaneously lead to error. I found a workaround:

```
154         $(CP) libmxml.so.1.4 $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)
155         $(LN) $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)/libmxml.so.1.4 $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)/libmxml.so
156         $(LN) $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)/libmxml.so.1.4 $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)/libmxml.so.1
```

First, copy the real file to the dir, then create 2 symbolic links in the dir one by one.

That's it. No errors reported any more.